# Pagination info missing in instagram api

Tags: pagination, instagram

I am using the most popular api via [instagram api](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)
In the document, it saying something about pagination and next_url but when I
use the link below with my app ID. I don't see any pagination info in the json.
Am i missing something?
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=CLIENT-ID
or
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=CLIENT-ID&count=10

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Some endpoints provide pagination and some do not, for some reason. For example  https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXX/media/recent?access_token=XXXX  should paginate. But the url you are pointing to is so active that paginating would be pointless.  Although it would be nice to have it consistent across the board,  this particular one can just be called again and again without worries of repeat.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  No matter what Pagination properties such as min_id, max_id, next_min_Id I pass in the second AJAX call seem to work .

Answer (score 2):

you should get the pagination info back in a an object callged "pagination"

```
"pagination": {
    "next_max_tag_id": "1335465136530",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "next_max_id": "1335465136530",
    "next_min_id": "1335465556125",
    "min_tag_id": "1335465556125",
    "next_url": "https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/tags\/cats\/media\/recent?callback=jQuery17201362594123929739_1335440328560&_=133544032857&client_id=xxx&max_tag_id=1335465136530"
}
```

Which has the next_url you are looking for

Comment: Any idea how to break down the JSON so that you get seperate objects associated with each "data" object?

Comment: hmm not sure what you mean, is this in regards to pagination?  what do you mean break down the json and which data objects?

Answer (score 2):

The pagination information will be empty if the requested user's feed has fewer posts than the default query count.  In other words, if the instagram account only has five pictures, there is no pagination info.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of documentation around pagination on the official API.

Check out this tutorial for more guidance and depth.

http://eduvoyage.com/search-instagram-pagination.html

You need to use the "min_tag_id" and "max_tag_id" to get the images you want.

As your using the endpoint to get popular images, you might want to try something like this.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?callback=?&client_id=YOURID&max_tag_id=1364206789229

But if you are after a specific tag, try something like this.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?callback=?&client_id=YOURID&max_tag_id=1364206789229

Comment: The problem is,  the is no pagination in the json

Comment: I got it, have to add max_tag_id. but what is that?

Answer (score 0):

`media/popular` endpoint does not have a pagination object. As Ryan Ore explained some endpoints provide pagination and some dot not.

You check whether the endpoint has a pagination or not by `"pagination": {}` object. If the object exists the endpoint has pagination.