# Instagram API error: Max_tag_id request

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm trying to develop a PHP application that reads all Media from Instagram searching by Hashtag.
This is my request string:

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/[my-tag]/media/recent?access_token=[my-acces-token]

and i'm receiving an error response like this:

> {"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}

Seems like a request to use "min_tag_id" and "max_tag_id" parameters but i don't know which value to use for these parameters. I tryed numbers like 0-1-10 but don't work, i get another error.

In the API documentation i can't find any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625173/how-does-instagrams-get-tags-tag-media-recent-pagination-actually-work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504014/pagination-info-missing-in-instagram-api

Comment: I forgot to mention that the application is in Sanbox mode. But in theory this is not a problem, the API have to work correctly.

Comment: Thank You Anant,
I had already seen those questions.
Doing some more tests I agree that using the endpoint
`code` ....com/v1/tags/CATS/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`code`
I can only see my images, not those of other profiles.
So if I have uploaded via my profile an image with the tag CATS and I make a request for the tag CATS then is returned to me only my picture.
But my aim is to get the pictures of all the profiles, not just mine.
How to do? It can be a problem of limitations to my application?
When I do I request the authentication socope = Public_content

Comment: Solved.. The problem is the Sandbox mode. In sandbox mode I can get only My images and images of other developers added to sanbox users of the application